# Slider stop working after first swipe on the IPhones

Tags: javascript, iphone, slider

As it mentioned in title, i have encountered strange bug on the Iphones, after first swipe, slider stop working and not carry on to register swipes anymore, i have tested slider on the several devices and on the all Androids devices as well as in Developer Tools in Chrome all works fine.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
  const prevButton = document.querySelector('.prev-button');
  const nextButton = document.querySelector('.next-button');
  const slides = Array.from(slider.children);
  const slideCount = slides.length;
  let slideIndex = 0;
  let startX = 0;
  let endX = 0;

  prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    slideIndex = (slideIndex - 1 + slideCount) % slideCount;
    slide();
  });

  nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    slideIndex = (slideIndex + 1) % slideCount;
    slide();
  });

  const slide = () => {
    const slideOffset = -slideIndex * slider.clientWidth;
    slider.style.transform = `translateX(${slideOffset}px)`;
  };

  
  slider.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart);
  slider.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove);
  slider.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd);

  function touchStart(e) {
    startX = e.touches[0].clientX;
  }

  function touchMove(e) {
    endX = e.touches[0].clientX;
    
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function touchEnd() {
    const swipeThreshold = 50; 
    const swipeDistance = startX - endX;

    if (swipeDistance > swipeThreshold) {
      
      slideIndex = (slideIndex + 1) % slideCount;
    } else if (swipeDistance < -swipeThreshold) {
      
      slideIndex = (slideIndex - 1 + slideCount) % slideCount;
    }
    
    slide();
    startX = 0;
    endX = 0;
  }

  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    slide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The touch event is most likely being cancelled due to a default event taking precedence. You can test this by adding a `touchcancel` listener and checking if it fires on iPhone.

If this is the case, you need to set the `touch-action` CSS property on the parent element to what the expected behavior is (this is probably a good idea anyways). If you are handling all touch actions yourself via JS, then you can set `touch-action: none` on the parent element.